# When does QGraphicsItem get destroyed in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, destroy, qgraphicsitem

It seems that a `QGraphicsItem` status goes from `To be destroyed by: C/C++` to `To be destroyed by: Python`, while not destroyed and still accessible. Is it an expected behavior ? If so, can someone explain ?

## Creation part

```
node = QGraphicsRectItem()
self.scene.addItem(node)

print("Deleted ? ", sip.isdeleted(node))
print("Owned by Python ? ", sip.ispyowned(node))
sip.dump(node)
```

**Output**

```
Deleted ?  False
Owned by Python ?  False
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem object at 0x7fcdb82371f8>
    Reference count: 3
    Address of wrapped object: 0x214bf80
    Created by: Python
    To be destroyed by: C/C++
    Parent wrapper: <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene object at 0x7fcdb821ea68>
    Next sibling wrapper: <__main__.Host object at 0x7fcdb8237dc8>
    Previous sibling wrapper: NULL
    First child wrapper: NULL
```

## Deletion part

```
self.scene.removeItem(node)

print("Deleted ? ", sip.isdeleted(node))
print("Owned by Python ? ", sip.ispyowned(node))
sip.dump(node)
```

**Output**

```
Deleted ?  False
Owned by Python ?  True
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem object at 0x7fcdb82371f8>
    Reference count: 2
    Address of wrapped object: 0x214bf80
    Created by: Python
    To be destroyed by: Python
    Parent wrapper: NULL
    Next sibling wrapper: NULL
    Previous sibling wrapper: NULL
    First child wrapper: NULL
```

One can see it is now owned by Python after deletion. And it still exists. Why ?

Comment: Do you expect that with removeItem () the item will be removed from memory? If so, removeItem() does not remove the item from memory, and the objective is to reuse that item in another scene so that It is the responsibility of the programmer to manage that memory, the same happens in Qt. Similar behavior has the QListWidgetItem.

Comment: @eyllanesc Agree. I don't expect that. The point is, using `PyQt`, I don't have an explicit destructor or `delete` instruction, as with C++. Do I have to force it manually then ? If so, what's the best PyQt'ish way to do that, instead of using sip or another solution from python (like `del`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [**add** the item to the scene, Qt takes ownership of it](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem), so you don't need to keep an explicit reference to it on the Python side. This means that when the scene is deleted, the C++ part of the item will be deleted as well - and if there are no other references held to the Python part, it will also be garbage-collected (so there will be nothing left).

When you [**remove** the item from the scene, ownership passes back to the caller](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem), who now has full responsiblity for deleting it. If `QGraphicsRectItem` inherited `QObject`, you could call `deleteLater()` to delete the C++ part - but this would still leave you with the empty Python wrapper, so it wouldn't really make much difference.

The way to delete a PyQt wrapper is the same as for any other python object - i.e. use `del`, or simply let it go out of scope and allow it to be garbage-collected in the normal way. There is no special PyQt way to delete such objects, because nothing special is needed.

In your example, you never actually make any attempt to delete the item, so the information reported by sip is entirely as expected.

Finally, note that it is always possible to delete the C++ part independently of the PyQt wrapper. If you do this, and then attempt to access the item's methods, you will get a `RuntimeError`:

```
>>> scene = QGraphicsScene()
>>> node = QGraphicsRectItem()
>>> scene.addItem(node)
>>> del scene
>>> node.rect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QGraphicsRectItem has been deleted
```

**UPDATE**:

Below is a demo that shows how the item is garbage-collected when it is removed from the scene and allowed to go out of scope. Of course, if there are any references held to the item elsewhere (i.e. if ref-count > 1), the item will not be deleted.

```
import sip, gc
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['test'])

scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()

def test():
    node = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem()
    scene.addItem(node)
    scene.removeItem(node)
    print("Deleted ? ", sip.isdeleted(node))
    print("Owned by Python ? ", sip.ispyowned(node))
    sip.dump(node)
    print()

test()

print('gc collect...')

gc.collect()

for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if isinstance(obj, QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
        print(obj)
        break
else:
    print('deleted')
```

Output:

```
Deleted ?  False
Owned by Python ?  True
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem object at 0x7f90f66d5798>
    Reference count: 3
    Address of wrapped object: 0x205bd80
    Created by: Python
    To be destroyed by: Python
    Parent wrapper: NULL
    Next sibling wrapper: NULL
    Previous sibling wrapper: NULL
    First child wrapper: NULL

gc collect...
deleted
```

Comment: `The ownership of item is passed on to the caller (i.e., QGraphicsScene will no longer delete item when destroyed).` makes sense now, didn't understand it that way. Also, `simply let it go out of scope and allow it to be garbage-collected in the normal way` never saw the node collected, even when calling gc.collect() explicitly. Finally, your advise is to `removeItem` and then let it be collected ? Because, as I said, it doesn't seem to be collected

Comment: @JustinIurman. That must be because you are holding on to some other references elsewhere in your code. I have added a demo to my answer that works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I was holding a local reference, inside the function where tests happened. My bad. I got now the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You don't let it go out of scope after deleting. It is removed from everything Qt, but Python still has the `node` variable you are using to reference the item.

Comment: `QGraphicsRectItem` doesn't inherit `QObject`.

Comment: Thanks. My bad. Updated.

Comment: Weird because a `node` (that inherits from `QObject` and so has `deleteLater`) is well deleted. Even if python still has a reference. What's the implementation behind `deleteLater` ?